# How to print out all the key words and available types of javascript via javascript?

Tags: javascript, reflection

I think it's something called `language reflection`. See [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)).

Print out something like:

```
'var', 'function', 'if', ...
'number', 'string', 'object', ...
```

Just for fun.

Comment: console.log('var'); it will print :P

Comment: http://aptana.com/reference/api/JSKeywords.index.html

Comment: 1. Go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords. 2. Press ctrl-P.

Comment: I want a language reflection solution. Different version of js may differ.

Comment: No such feature is available. Reflection does not refer to reflecting on the language itself.

Comment: Not fun :( I need it for compression to one letter

Comment: console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)) //reserved names but not keywords